# Create two moving images in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have an image of a vertical line, and want to create two of them. I want them to randomly spread apart and close the gap (while maintaining a minimum and maximum distance - I'm waiting to fix this first), while moving along the x-axis. The y coords don't move.

There are many examples of creating more complex sprites and games using pygame, but I can't find one simple enough to pinpoint what I'm supposed to do, so any help is appreciated. This code is based off of a simple example found [here.](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=moving_sprites.py)

This is the very basic code that I have so far.

```
class Squeeze(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.img_load()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += random.randint(-1, 1)
        if self.rect.x >= 1920:
            self.rect.x += -1
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            self.rect.x += 1

    def img_load(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1920
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
FPS = 60
wall = pygame.image.load('wall.png')
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
for i in range(2):
    wall = Squeeze()
    wall.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
    wall.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    wall_list.add(wall)

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    wall_list.update()
    wall_list.draw(screen)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

I'm confused about the pygame.sprite.Group() deal. How do I get the two images to load and operate on them separately? Any other advice is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically *a "sprite" is a visible game object* in your game. Pygames [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) class is known as the "*base class*" for all these objects.

Every time when creating the `Squeeze` class, you *derive* form Pygames build-in sprite base class:

```
class Squeeze(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

Each object (or instance) of the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class holds

- an [`.update()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.update) method and
- an `.image` and
- an `.rect` attribute.

As the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) states, "* ... derived classes will want to override the `Sprite.update()` and assign a `Sprite.image` and `Sprite.rect` attributes.*"
You did this by calling the your `img_load()` method in the `__init__()` method of your `Squeeze` class.

The problem is now that your `.rect` is assigned to the same size as your screen (`self.image = pygame.Surface([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])`) and the `.image` attribute has the same color as your display screen, so you can´t see it.

Try to modify your `img_load()` method to

```
def img_load(self, img):
    self.image = img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

As you can see, the modified `img_load()` method needs an image object -- which is passed to the `img` argument. So you also need to change your `__init__()` method:

```
def __init__(self, img):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.img_load(img)
```

When now instantiating (e.g. creating an object of a class) a `Squeeze` object, you need to pass an image (in our case `wall_img`) to the constructor:

```
#... main programm

wall_img = pygame.image.load('wall.png') #load an image
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group() #create a sprite group

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
for i in range(2):
    wall = Squeeze(wall_img) #create a sprite
    wall.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
    wall.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)

    wall_list.add(wall) #add the sprite to the sprite group
```

---

The second build-in class you use is the [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) class -- a container, which can hold and manage (modify) sprites it contains.

Calling the `.update()` method of a sprite group instance, Pygame *automatically calls* the `update()` methods of all sprites in this group. This means you can control a sprites behavior by implementing its `update()` method, as you did:

```
#update method of the Squeeze class
def update(self):
    #any logic which changes sprite
    self.rect.x += random.randint(-1, 1)
    if self.rect.x >= 1920:
        self.rect.x += -1
    if self.rect.x <= 0:
        self.rect.x += 1
```

By calling

```
wall_list.draw(screen)
```

your spites will be blitted onto the `screen` surface using the `.image` attribute for the source surface, and `.rect` for the position.

If you now wont to have different images you just need to pass other images (or surfaces) to the `Squeeze` constructor:

```
#... main programm

wall_imgs = [pygame.image.load('wall.png'),
             pygame.image.load('other_wall.png')] #load images in list
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group() #create a sprite group

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
for i in range(2):
    wall = Squeeze(wall_imgs[i]) #create a sprite
    wall.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
    wall.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)

    wall_list.add(wall) #add the sprite to the sprite group
```

I hope this helps you a little bit :)

Comment: This was way more than I expected, thanks so much. The last thing I'm trying to implement is maintaining a min and max x-distance between the two images. The problem is I don't know how to keep track of which image is which when calling update(), so I don't know which way I should move the current rect. Any pointers?